# Why is this Jinn processor better for iota?

Tags: ternary, jinn, ternary-hardware

Everyone is waiting for the ternary Jinn processor. But why is it so important for IOTA and who will include this processor instead of a normal one?

Comment: Invites pure speculation at this point. What makes it a bad SE question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know too much info on JINN processor and it's not an absolute must for IOTA to function as it's already up and running now. Based on rumors the JINN chip is specifically designed to process the PoW insanely fast using ternary architecture. We really don't know if they might even be incorporated into future Routers/cellphone boards as standards. I really wouldn't be surprised as the IOTA foundation already has a lot of talks/partnership with some of the largest IOT manufactures; bosh, cisco, etc..